# How to access a Particular Value from a struct

Tags: ios, swift

I created a struct `UserModel.swift` to store the json data:-

```
struct UserModel {

    var id: Int = 0
    var uuid:Int = 0
    var user_name: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var email: String = ""

    init(json: [String:Any]) {

        if let obj = json["id"] as? Int {
            self.id = obj
        }

        if let obj = json["uuid"] as? Int {
            self.uuid = obj
        }

        if let obj = json["user_name"] as? String {
            self.user_name = obj
        }

        if let obj = json["name"] as? String {
            self.name = obj
        }

        if let obj = json["email"] as? String {
            self.email = obj
        }
    }
}
```

Now I used Alamofire to get the json in my `ViewController.Swift` file and I stored my struct by creating a variable I am successfully get the json and stored it in my struct.

```
var userModel = [UserModel]()
private func getList() {

    progressHUD.show(in: view, animated: true)

    //          let uuid = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "uuid")

    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("list_request?device_token=\(device_token ?? "")&uuid=794849"), method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        self.progressHUD.dismiss()

        guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else {return}
        guard let data = json["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}
        printD(data)
        guard let status = json["status"] as? Bool else { return}
        printD(status)

        if status == true {
            guard let data = json["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}
            for userData in data {
                self.userModel.append(UserModel(json: userData))
                printD(self.userModel)
            }
            CommonClass.shared.showSuccessMessage("\(json["msg"] as? String ?? "")", inViewController: self)
        }

        else if status == false {
            CommonClass.shared.showErrorMessage("\(json["msg"] as? String ?? "")", inViewController: self)
        }
        else  {
            CommonClass.shared.showErrorMessage("Server Connection Error. Please try again later", inViewController: self)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am getting I have to use my userModel data in another api in same class and I don't know How Can I do that. In rejectRequest() function I need to access some of my struct data but I don't know how can I do that. Please help?

```
private func rejectRequest() {
    let user = userModel // I need to use userModel data for parameter 
    let param: [String:Any] = ["from_user": "", "to_user": "", "request_id": "", "device_token": device_token ?? ""]

    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("end_request"), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a struct to hold common data that is shared across the app. Here's a sample for a DataController that can hold different models or arrays / dicts of models:

```
struct DataController {

    // MARK: - User management

    struct Users {
        static var users: [User] = []
        static var currentUser: User = User()

        static func addUser(_ user: User) {
             users.append(user)
        }

        static func findUserById(_ id: Int) -> User? {
            // Find the users that match the id (should only be one!)
            let users = user.filter { $0.id = id }
            return users.count == 1 ? users[0] : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Add a user:

```
 DataController.Users.addUser(user)
```

Access from elsewhere by:

```
DataController.Users.currentUser
```

Find a user by an id:

```
if let user = DataController.Users.findUserById(id) {
     ... do stuff ... 
}
```

Incidentally, might be simpler to use a `guard` statement when parsing your JSON data:

```
init(json: [String:Any]) {

    guard 
        let id = json["id"] as? Int,
        let uuid = json["uuid"] as? Int,
        let user_name = json["user_name"] as? String,
        let name = json["name"] as? String,
        let email = json["email"] as? String
    else {
        return // Fail
    }

    self.id = id
    self.uuid = uuid
    self.user_name = user_name
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
}
```

Comment: but how can I access a particular value from struct I need to use `id` value from struct to pass this value in parameter here `"request_id": "here i need id from struct"`

Comment: Okay but do I access any value from this method like uuid, name etc.??

Comment: Get the user by id then access values via dot-notation, e.g. `user.uuid`, `user.name`, etc.

Comment: can you explain what is `User` inside the `Users` struct ?

Comment: I just used User as an example strict. Replace with your user model.