# need to get the country name from open api

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

Needs to get country name from below api call :

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all

My code :

```
var arrRes = []
func getCountry() {
    let Url: String = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"   
    Alamofire.request(Url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        do {
            if let datas = responseData.result.value {
                let data  = (datas as AnyObject).data(using: .utf8)!
                let parseData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                for country in parseData {
                    if let name = country["name"] as? String {
                        print(name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

getting error here : `'Any' is not convertible to 'AnyObject'` on below line `let data  = (datas as AnyObject).data(using: .utf8)!`..

I need to get only name and append to my array.Any other idea or solution to achieve that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a Particular Value from a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008905/how-to-access-a-particular-value-from-a-struct)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `do catch` block of statement with this.

```
do {
    if let countries = responseData.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
        for country in countries {
            if let name = country["name"] as? String {
                print(name)
            }
        }
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: `Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: Any, options: [Any])'` on `let parseData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datas, options: []).  i already tried this too..that time also same error

Comment: You do not need the `let error as NSError` part. Simply do `} catch { print(error) }`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @rmaddy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, its working fine for me.

```
let urlStr = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"
let setFinalURl = urlStr.addingPercentEncoding (withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: setFinalURl)!)
request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON
    { (responseObject) -> Void in

        if responseObject.result.isSuccess
        {
            print(responseObject.result.value!)

            if "\(String(describing: responseObject.response!.statusCode))" == "200"
            {
                let result = responseObject.result.value! as AnyObject

                let countryNamesArr = result.value(forKey: "name") as! NSArray
                print(countryNamesArr)
            }
            else
            {
                // handle error
            }
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure
        {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line

<strike>`let data  = (datas as AnyObject).data(using: .utf8)!`</strike>

and in optional binding just assign `data`, since `value` is of type `Data?`, from optional binding you get `Data`

```
if let data = responseData.result.value
```

then don't forget to downcast your json to array `[String:Any]`

```
...jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:Any]]
```

... then don't forget to unwrap this array or you wouldn't be able to iterate through it in for each loop

---

Also note that since there is `Codable`, you should use it instead of `JSONSerialization`. Then you can decode your json using `JSONDecoder` to your own model which conforms to protocol `Decodable`.

Comment: Valid answer. I'd suggest trying to avoid the `as!`, you could make it `as?` for safety ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let name: String  
}
```

---

```
func getCountry() {

    let urlStr = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"
    Alamofire.request(urlStr).responseData { (data) in

        do {
             guard let data = data.data else { return }
             let res  = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
             print(res)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: again Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1fa903a70) to 'NSData' (0x1fa901dd8)

Comment: @david no need to make the responseJson if you need data with Codable do reponseData

Answer (score 0):

As a simple approach, you could implement `getCountry()` like this:

```
func getCountry() {
    let url: String = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        if let resultValue = response.result.value, let countryObjects = resultValue as? [[String: Any]] {
            let countryNames = countryObjects.compactMap { $0["name"] as? String }
            print(countryNames)
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, there is no need to use `JSONSerialization` to get the country names; According to the API response, `responseData.result.value` is an array of countries (dictionaries), each dictionary has a "name" value, what you should do is to *map* the response to an array of string. `countryNames` should contains what are you looking for.

The benefit of using `compactMap` is to avoid any `nil` name, so `countryNames` should be `[String]` instead of `[String?]`.

However, if you believe that you would need to transform the whole response objects into a custom objects (instead of dictionaries), I would highly recommend to follow the approach of using [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable).

Answer (score 0):

My code, its working well for me.

Swift 5

```
 public func getCountry(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
            let url: String = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"
            AF.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
                do {
                    guard let data = responseData.data else { return }
                    let res  = try JSONDecoder().decode([CountryName].self,from:data)
                    completion(self.getCountryName(countryName: res))
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

 struct CountryName: Codable {
   let name: String
 }

 private func getCountryName(countryName:[CountryName]) -> [String]{
      var country:[String]  = []
      for index in 0...countryName.count - 1{
           country.append(countryName[index].name)
      }
    return country
 }
```